# How to make the iPhone show the location authorization popup again after dismissing it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, popup, location

I'm trying to integrate the `[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]` but ever since the pop up showed once on my app, I tried everything to make it show it again. I deleted the app from the phone, changed the name of the app, change the bundle id, name and app name. It keeps remembering it.

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the phone, open Settings, goto General, scroll to the bottom, tap Reset, tap "Reset Location Warnings".  It's the phone that remembers the settings, not the app.